# Firebird - select master-detail

Tags: firebird

Olá. Preciso fazer uma consulta às tabelas do sistema, que me retorne o seguinte resultado:

```
 Relation_Name, Field_Id, Field_Name, Field_source, Field_type
```

para cada tabela (Relation_Name) definida pelo usuário (exceto Views). Ou seja, para cada tabela, os campos (Field_Name) que a compõem e para cada campo, o Field_source e o Field_type.

Estou usando o seguinte comando:

```
select distinct
             RelFields.RDB$Relation_Name   as "Rel Name",
             RelFields.RDB$Field_Id        as "Field Id",
             RelFields.RDB$Field_Name      as "Field Name",
             RelFields.RDB$Field_Source    as "Field Source",
                Fields.RDB$Field_Type      as "Field type"
from
                       RDB$Relations       as  Relations,
                       RDB$Relation_Fields as  RelFields
join
                       RDB$Fields          as     Fields
         on (Fields   .RDB$Field_Name    =     RelFields.RDB$Field_Name)
where
             Relations.RDB$Relation_Type = '0'                          and
             Relations.RDB$Relation_Name = RelFields.RDB$Relation_Name  and
  substring (Relations.RDB$Relation_Name    from 1 for 4)   <>   'IBE$' and
             Relations.RDB$System_Flag   = '0'

order by
             RelFields.RDB$Relation_Name,
             RelFields.RDB$Field_Name
```

mas alguns Field_Names são omitidos aleatoriamente para certas tabelas.

Alguem proderia me apontar o erro no comando acima, ou então corrigí-lo? Grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria algo assim talvez?

```
select distinct RelFields.RDB$RELATION_NAME as "Rel Name", 
                RelFields.RDB$FIELD_ID as "Field Id",
                RelFields.RDB$FIELD_NAME as "Field Name",
                RelFields.RDB$FIELD_SOURCE as "Field Source",
                   Fields.RDB$FIELD_TYPE as "Field type"
from RDB$RELATIONS as RELATIONS
join RDB$RELATION_FIELDS as RelFields on 
     Relations.RDB$RELATION_NAME = RelFields.RDB$RELATION_NAME
join RDB$FIELDS as Fields on 
     Fields.RDB$FIELD_NAME = RelFields.RDB$FIELD_SOURCE
where Relations.RDB$VIEW_SOURCE is null and 
      Relations.RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG = 0 and 
      substring (Relations.RDB$Relation_Name from 1 for 4) <> 'IBE$'
order by RelFields.RDB$RELATION_NAME, RelFields.RDB$FIELD_NAME
```

Na minha opinião não seria necessário colocar o *substring* ali no final do SQL.

Comment: Obrigado Cava. Funcionou perfeito!